# Programmatically "Enable reporting of offensive content" on community site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I "Enable reporting of offensive content" on community site Programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable / disable reporting via the `EnableDisableAbuseReports` method of the internal class `Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.FunctionalityEnablers`.
The value of the `vti_CommunityEnableReportAbuse` web property has effect only to the value of the `Enable reporting of offensive content` checkbox on `Site Settings / Community Settings` page

Here is a sample implementation in `PowerShell` that performs both steps you need:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourSite/YourCommunityWeb

# this command has only effect on the check box in the UI
$web.AllProperties["vti_CommunityEnableReportAbuse"] = "true"
$web.Update()

# the real job is done here
# 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb'
$spWeb = $web.Site.AllWebs[$web.ID]

# get a reference for the Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal assembly
$spPortalAssembly = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ? { $_.Location -ne $Null -And $_.Location.Split('\\')[-1].Equals('Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.dll') }
# get the type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.FunctionalityEnablers'
$functionalityEnablersType = $spPortalAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.FunctionalityEnablers")
# get the method info for 'EnableDisableAbuseReports'
$mi_EnableDisableAbuseReports = $functionalityEnablersType.GetMethod("EnableDisableAbuseReports")
# invoke the static 'EnableDisableAbuseReports' method
$mi_EnableDisableAbuseReports.Invoke($null, @($spWeb, $True))
```

If you need it in C# (add `Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal` to the referneced assemblies in your project, and you need `using System.Reflection;` as well):

```
web.AllProperties["vti_CommunityEnableReportAbuse"] = "true";
web.Update();

// get an assembly refernce to "Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal" via an arbitrary public class from the assembly
Assembly spPortalAssembly = typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.PortalContext).Assembly;

Type functionalityEnablersType = spPortalAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.FunctionalityEnablers");
MethodInfo mi_EnableDisableAbuseReports = functionalityEnablersType.GetMethod("EnableDisableAbuseReports");
mi_EnableDisableAbuseReports.Invoke(null, new object[] { web, true });
```

Comment: thank you, I tried you code using SP server c# code, but I can't find the "FunctionalityEnablers" under Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal

Comment: As I wrote, it is internal, non-public, non-documented. You can find it using tools like Reflector or JetBrains dotPeek, or via the classes in the System.Reflection namespace. You can of course access the internal classes from C# as well, but it requires you to use Reflection as well.